# Trouble With Subscribing To Peripheral Characteristic In Xamarin On IOS13

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios13

I use BLE to connect to a device. The device has a characteristic which returns value every 20ms. I am subscribing to a characteristic with SetNotifyValue(true, characteristic). On iOS 13 the amount of characteristic values is so large that it blocks the entire application. Previous versions do not have this problem. Based on my application output the amount of data received in iOS 13 is far greater.

The characteristic values are added to a queue. I then read / dequeue them in another thread. On previous iOS versions, the queue never gets longer than single digit size. On iOS 13 the queue quickly grows in size. It reached 10 000+ before I stopped the application. The values are being added so fast that the thread never gets to access the queue and dequeue them.

Has anyone encountered this or similar problem? I am seeking advice / suggestions on how I can further investigate the cause of this behaviour.

I wanted to see if every subscription to characteristic does this. I checked battery % characteristic and subscribing to it works fine.

I tried emptying the queue if the size reaches more than n before values are added to queue. This did not help because the values were still coming at the same speed and the other thread still could not access the queue to dequeue values.

I removed SetNotifyValue(true, characteristic) from the problematic characteristic and added a timer that would read the characteristic value in intervals. I tried different intervals (20ms / 50ms / 500ms / 10000ms). It would seem it still somehow subscribes to the characteristic as the application output is the same as before.

I am currently unsure if I am allowed to show any / how much of the code.

Here is the output of the application. Each line prints out last 22 received values. I have shortened it for easier overview. I added this to show the speed of data received. This is printed from UpdatedCharacterteristicValue.

iOS 13:

[13:27:38.0410] 22 values

[13:27:38.0416] 22 values

[13:27:38.0423] 22 values

[13:27:38.0430] 22 values

[13:27:38.0435] 22 values

[13:27:38.0440] 22 values

[13:27:38.0445] 22 values

[13:27:38.0450] 22 values

[13:27:38.0455] 22 values

[13:27:38.0461] 22 values

[13:27:38.0465] 22 values

iOS 10.3.4:

[13:20:19.0000] 22 values

[13:20:19.0840] 22 values

[13:20:20.0680] 22 values

[13:20:21.0491] 22 values

[13:20:22.0361] 22 values

[13:20:23.0171] 22 values

[13:20:24.0009] 22 values

[13:20:24.0852] 22 values

[13:20:25.0690] 22 values

[13:20:26.0500] 22 values

[13:20:27.0310] 22 values

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a call to readValue in UpdatedCharacteristicValue.

When looking in nrfConnect the device does not have read option for this characteristic, only notify. My guess is that previous versions handled this differently. On the iOS 13 the subscription was made again.

After removing the readValue() call the application now behaves as expected.

I would also like to thank Apple Support for helpfully recommending me to contact the hardware staff. It was cruicial in finding the error in my code.